# Is it possible to run TypeScript and JavaScript in the same react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I have created an app in JS react. To continue my work i have come up with a file in TSX. What should I do ?

Can I import a TSX file and interact with it whithin a JSX file ?
Should I transform my whole app to TSX for it to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Kyano said, yes you can.
But it is not the right thing to do (a.k.a it is not a good practise).

You can however :

- translate the tsx into jsx and then import the jsx.
- Rewright the tsx file by your own in pure jsx
- Move your all app into tsx (if you intend to).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you just need to include a tsconfig file, though it would be better to stick to one.